# Given an NFA A and a regular expression B, is the problem of determining L(A) = L(B) decidable?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, undecidability, regular-expressions

I have having trouble with the following question:

> Given an NFA $A$ and a regular expression $B$, consider the problem of determining if $L(A) = L(B)$. Is this decidable? Prove your answer.

Comment: What did you try?   You know that a language is regular if and only if fit is decided by an NFA if and only if it is decided by a DFA?  So your question boils down to equivalence (bisimilarity?) of two DFAs.

Comment: To add to the comment, every regular language has a minimal DFA recognizing it, and this DFA is unique (modulo isomorphisms).  This turns the problem into a minimization problem and then a graph isomorphism problem.

Comment: @PålGD - it may be understood from your comment that the problem is in NP (graph-iso), while it is actually PSPACE-complete even when you are given 2 NFAs.

Comment: Actually it's linear after you get two DFAs

Comment: @Shaull Well, I never claim the minimization problem to be solvable in polynomial time.  And you are right to point out that this step indeed might take exponentially long time.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Transform both into DFAs $M_1$ and $M_2$; from them construct DFAs for $L_1 \cap \overline{L_2}$ and $\overline{L_1} \cap L_2$, and check that neither accepts anything.

As noted in the comments, the NFA to DFA construction can give an exponential increase in number of states, same for regular expression to DFA, so this doesn't prove the problem is in NP. Luckily you weren't asked about that ;-)